# How to scale a web page for different resolutions?

Tags: website-design, responsive-design, scale

I have a web-page for devices(smartphones/tablets).
I have used media queries to make it responsive and have used rem units for all measurements.
I have set default html/body font-size:62.5% and then calculated all other rem units.
Also for each breakpoint i have a set of css.

But it seems that the font size and other element doesn't scale as the resolution increases.
What should i do to make it good? or What else i am missing here?

Comment: You wouldn't normally *want* font sizes to change much if at all. That said, if you are using REM, that is related to the *root* font size. Are you changing the html/body font size with each breakpoint?

Comment: i have changed the font-size of each break point..individually..as i am not changing everything..for all brakpoints

Comment: i dont increase the root font but i do change fonts for different breakpoints

Comment: How are you attempting to change the font sizes? I think you may want to ask this over on StackOverflow and provide some code samples for us to look at.

Comment: But sometimes it requires only few elements to resize or align.. then on that cases how to handle.. any idea?

Comment: Related:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36364/which-is-the-more-preferable-font-size-reset

Answer (score 1):

Use width:100%; for the full screen / div in your web page and if you mean responsive use this code for ipad / phone

> @media only screen and (max-width : 768px // for ipad
>
> 480 //for> phone){
>
> }

And set this in your html file to read the responsive css

> < meta content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width"
> name="viewport" >